# Array to string conversion SYmfony Sql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have an sql request:

```
 $listUsers=$connection->prepare("SELECT u.id as userid From user u , account a where (a.id_parent=$id_account OR  a.id=$id_account) and u.id_account=a.id ");
            $listUsers->execute();
            $users=$listUsers->fetchColumn();
```

but fetchColumn return just one result, and I want a set of list user id to use it in the next request.

```
 $listPush=$connection->prepare("select id from Table_name where id_user in (?));
 $listPush->bindValue(1, $users);
            $listPush->execute();
            $idpushs=$listPush->fetchColumn();
```

but this return just one result. Any Idea to replace fetchColumn by other request or using doctrince.

Comment: fetchColumn returns a single column from the next row of a result set. Try fetchAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your logic, you can simply fetch all your users and implode it.

```
$listUsers=$connection->prepare("SELECT u.id as userid From user u , account a where (a.id_parent=$id_account OR  a.id=$id_account) and u.id_account=a.id ");
$listUsers->execute();
$users=$listUsers->fetchAll();
$userIds = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $userIds[] = $user['userid'];
}
$users = implode(',', $userIds); //that hurts me so hard to code like this with symfony :'(
```

Fetch colum will only return the column of the **next row**. So for your second piece of code, you can loop over results.

But, if you're are using a framework like symfony, you have many other ways to make it cleaner. Just check out the symfony doc to use `repository` `relations` and more generally `doctrine`

Comment: the problem that the result is an array like this: 'array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'userid' => string '10' (length=2)'

Comment: Updated. Please consider the end of my answer :)